# bxslider isn't displaying images until page resize with responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bxslider

I am trying to implement bxslider on a responsive page (using Bootstrap) and for the first 2 or 3 times it is showing images correctly. However after that it just shows a narrow white band:

[image]

If I resize the browser then the bxSlider resizes correctly and displays the images.

My partial code contains the following code (Note, this populates a div as a result of an AJAX call)

```
<ul class="product-view-bxslider">
  <% @product.images.each do |image| %>
      <li><%= image_tag image.image.url %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('slider initialising');
    $('.product-view-bxslider').bxSlider({
      onSliderLoad: function(){
        console.log('finished loading');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The bxslider setup is working correctly as I do always get the expected output to console.

I have replicated this behaviour in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

From my searches most people who have had resize issues with bxslider were having issues **when** resizing the browser, not on initial load.

**Edit**

Setting an initial fixed height for the layout of the bxslider displays all images at once (including 2 extra - which I assume are for buffering the navigation). Again only a browser resize forces the bxslider to resize and display correctly.

```
.bx-viewport.bx-viewport {
  min-height: 90px;
}
```

[image]

This is suggesting that perhaps the issue isn't, as I originally believed, a result of misbehaving with responsive layouts.

Perhaps the following information is pertinent to this question. I am using Rails and the page I posted earlier is a result of an AJAX invocation of `ProductsController#show` action. There doesn't appear to be anything esoteric going on here:

*ProductsController#show*

```
  def show
  end
```

*show.js.erb*

```
  $('#product-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products/show') %>")
```

*_show.html.erb*

as posted at start of question

*invocation*

```
<%= link_to 'Show', product, remote: true %>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a known issue. Why do you wanna resize browser?

Comment: That's the whole point ... I do not want to resize the browser to get it working. I'm having an issue where images are **not** displayed **until** I resize the browser.

Comment: Oh shoot... Yeah, can you try to trigger a `$(window).trigger("resize")` action?

Comment: So trigger the bxSlider call when your Ajax call returns, not when the page loads. Or trigger a resize event when the Ajax code is doe and populates the data.

Comment: @epascarello - ok for clarity, I'm using Rails and letting that handle the AJAX by simply invoking my action through a link using `remote: true`. Server side I am simply rendering a js.erb page which contains the following `$('#product-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products/show') %>")`. I don't think the issue lies here does it? Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place - I suspected the responsive design to be the culprit.

Comment: Is the JavaScript code part of the html you are adding to the page? Or is it on the page to start?

Comment: all that code I have in my question is contained with the `products/_show.html.erb`. I should add it's cut for brevity ... there is a lot more html in that with responsive layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens to my projects when the first slide has a video. bxSlider sometimes will go to a strange default height if it takes too long on initial calculation of `.bx-viewport`. Typically, it will reload the correct height on a refresh or even a transition of a slide. Try this:

> ```
> .bx-viewport.bx-viewport {
>    min-height: 90vh;
> }
> ```

Adjust the value to your specific needs, but I recommend that you use an intrinsic or absolute unit of measurement such as vh or px, and avoid relative measurements like percentages or em.

Another fix is like the previous one, but counter-intuitive:

> ```
> `$('.bx-viewport`).height(0).css('min-height', '80vh')`;
> ```

@David has found the solution by using the opposite of what I use, suggesting that his site burdens bxSlider less than mine does. bxSlider does not hang on every loading error or timeout, it has a tendency to continue and start making shortcuts. Unfortunately, the calculation for `.bx-viewport`'s height is a common shortcut victim, resulting in a narrow bxSlider (`.bx-viewport {height:0}`).

> ```
> `$('.bx-viewport').css('height', '');
> ```

This and previous techniques will ***"wake up"*** bxSlider into recalculating `.viewport` height. Either one does the same thing, but mileage varies per user.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this isn't working either. It displays all images and transition doesn't result in recalculation of height. Again resizing the browser forces correct behaviour ... however this has given some insight ... it's suggesting that it's not an issue with behaving badly with responsive layout.

Comment: There's another way to wake up bxSlider, see update at bottom of post.

Comment: That code does take effect but its the same behaviour as before unfortunately - I have updated my question as a result of this insight.

Comment: hmm strange - after being inspired by your answer I started playing around in the browser and found the issue seems to be with `height:0px;` for the `bx-viewport` class. Added the following to the <script> tag and it actually behaves correctly: `$('.bx-viewport').css('height', '');` If you modify your solution I can accept - if you have any insight as to whats going on here that would be great, if not I will just accept this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: @David Great I'm glad you resolved your issue and I'm happy that bxSlider is becoming more predictable. Answer is updated, sir. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, this might work.

```
$(function () {
  // Your code.
  $(element).bxSlider({
    // options.
  });
  // Add this.
  $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

So, all that you need to do is, add this little code after bxSlider loading:

```
$('.product-view-bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSliderLoad: function(){
    console.log('finished loading');
  }
});
// Add this.
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work - reading further into this I found the following information : *jQuery's trigger does not actually trigger the native "resize" event* - it only fires the resize events that have been bound. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the info @David... Will see if there's anything else I could do.